# Understading ostream and how to declare in a class definition

Tags: c++, class, methods, ostream

Hi guys recently i'm starting to understand better c++ and i found different problems and most of them are starting to be clear. One thing that i've not understood is a error that the compiler found  when i try to declare a ostream or the every stream in a class declaration. For example

```
class Test{
  stringbuff buff;
  ostream out (&buff)
```

;
    }

The compiler returns this error message:

```
expected identifier before ‘&’ token
```

Oneother is when i try with:

```
stringstream stream(std::in|std::out);
```

compiler returns

```
error: ‘std::ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::in’ is not a type
   stringstream out(ios::in|ios::out);
```

The question is why can't i call these 'functions' in class declaration and what king of methods are. For example to be more clear how can declare a same methoud to use in this in the same way of ostream o (method);

Thanks to all and sorry for my english.

Comment: `ostream out{ &buff };` will fix your error. I'm too tired, hopefully someone will write an answer to explain why and other solutions.

Comment: Post the real code, complete with semicolons, that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that statement `ostream out (&buff) ;` is treated by compiler as an attempt to declare a function member, not a data member ; that is a generalized case of the [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

"Using the new uniform initialization syntax introduced in C++11 solves this issue" for in-class initialization also : `ostream out{ &buff };`.

To be more specific, c++11 just allows you to use *direct-initialization* with `{}` or *copy-initialization* with `=`, and not `()` in any of its "direct-init" usages for data members in-class initialization.

Another option is to initialize your data member within constructor's init list.

```
class Test
{
  std::stringbuf buff ;
  std::ostream out ;
  public :
    Test () : out( & buff ) { }
} ;
```